# Rails: Doorkeeper custom response from context

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-5, doorkeeper

We are using Doorkeeper gem to authenticate our users through an API. Everything is working fine since we've implemented it few years ago, we are using the `password` grant flow as in the example:

```
resource_owner_from_credentials do |_routes|
  user = User.active.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:username])

  if user&.valid_password?(params[:password])
    sign_in(user, force: true)
    user
  end
end
```

Doorkeeper is coupled with Devise, which enable `reconfirmable` strategy. As you can see in the code above, we are only allowing `active` users (a.k.a users with a confirmed email) to connect:

```
User.active.find_.....
```

### Problem

Our specifications changed and now we want to return a different error on login (against `/oauth/token`) depending if the user has confirmed its email or not.
Right now, if login fails, Doorkeeper is returning the following JSON:

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "The provided authorization grant is invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to another client."
}
```

Ideally, we want to be able to return a custom description if and only if the current email trying to login is `unconfirmed`

We've checked the documentation on Doorkeeper but it does not seems to have an easy way (if any at all) to do this. The fact that `resource_owner_from_credentials` method is located in the config adds too much magic and not enough flexibility.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok so after digging a little bit, we found an easy way to work around this issue by overriding `Doorkeeper::TokensController`.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class TokensController < Doorkeeper::TokensController
  before_action :check_if_account_is_pending, only: :create

  private

  def check_if_account_is_pending
    user = User.find_by(email: params['username'])
    render json: unconfirmed_account_error if user && !user.confirmed?
  end

  def unconfirmed_account_error
    { error: 'invalid', error_description: 'You must validate your email address before login' }
  end
end
```

We also needed to make sure the routes were pointing to the custom controller:

```
use_doorkeeper do
  controllers tokens: 'tokens'
end
```

Hope it can helps someone in the future